# css not working properly on mobile devices (Mi Browser)

Tags: html, css, next.js, mobile-browser, xiaomi

My css is working as expected in browsers like chrome (mobile). But when I try with Mi Browser, (native browser on xiaomi, it doesn't work properly.

I'm using Next.js and this is my head tag:

```
<Head>
<meta charSet="UTF-8" />
<title>Nutryin</title>
<meta
  name="viewport"
  content="width=device-width; initial-scale=1.0;"
/>
<link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" />
<link
  href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Dosis:wght@400;500&display=swap"
  rel="stylesheet"
/>
</Head>
```

website: https://nutryn-website.nutryn.vercel.app

screenshot on chrome:
[image]

screenshot on mi browser:
[image]

Comment: "CSS not working properly" - was it your intention to limit the audience? I don't have one of their phones or the ability to read your mind. Many others here are in the same position. _What_ doesn't work properly? (It's likely a browser bug in those phones)

Comment: @enhzflep sorry, I added screenshots now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

have you checked that specified css functions are supported by mi browser? go to w3schools or anywhere to check if browser and its version support your css functions or not.